# How to move divs when you have a smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a difficult time using push and pull to move my divs for smaller screens.

Divs on larger screen:
[A] [B] [C]

How I would like for them to look on smaller screens:
[A] [B]
[  C  ]

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This is straightforward using bootstrap's grid system, so you'll have to expand your question to explain what you've tried so far and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First you can import Bootstrap to your page by including this line of code between your  `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

Then you can play with classes like `col-md-*` or `col-xs-*` to rearrange your Divs according to the screen size.

More info on CSS with Bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)!

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap is ok and good choice , but you can do more customization with your decision , do this way :

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

.yourDIV {

width : 45%;
margin:2%;

}

}
```

this will work for screens with size of 500px and smaller, but you can change in your way.

Comment: Most people using bootstrap simply load the css and use it, but the better way to do it is to use the `less` or `scss` sources and customise the parameters yourself.